# Matplotlib subplot alignment and equal spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make an image with multiple subplots using matplotlib. That part is no problem. What I have been struggling with is alignment. Specifically, having the outside edges of the plots aligned and having equal spacing between the plots (the same space horizontally and vertically).

I have been able to get it working with no spacing between plots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.set_cmap('jet')
plt.close()

dim1 = 81
dim2 = 445
rad = 10

arr1 = np.random.rand(dim1, dim2) # Representative data, first plot
arr1[round(dim1/2 - rad):round(dim1/2 + rad), round(dim1/2 - rad):round(dim1/2 + rad)] += 6
arr1[round(dim1/2 - rad):round(dim1/2 + rad), round(-dim1/2 - rad):round(-dim1/2 + rad)] += 3

arr2 = arr1[:, :dim1] # Second plot
arr3 = arr1[:, -dim1:] # Third plot


xpix = dim2 # sudo x pixels in the image
ypix = xpix/2 + dim1 # sudo y pixels for the image
ratio = xpix/ypix # ratio of the width to height for the image

size = 7

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (size*ratio, size))

grid = plt.GridSpec(2, 2, wspace = 0, hspace = 0, left = 0, right = 1, top = 1, bottom = 0, height_ratios = [dim1, xpix/2])

ax1=fig.add_subplot(grid[0,:]) # Top plot
ax1.axis(False)
#ax1.set_anchor('N')
ax1.imshow(arr1, aspect = 'equal')

ax2=fig.add_subplot(grid[1,0]) # Bottom left plot
ax2.axis(False)
ax2.set_anchor('SW')
ax2.imshow(arr2, aspect = 'equal')

ax3=fig.add_subplot(grid[1,1]) # Bottom right plot
ax3.axis(False)
ax3.set_anchor('SE')
ax3.imshow(arr3, aspect = 'equal')

plt.show()
```

Which gives me the attached output.
[No spacing plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLiMe.png)

However, after many attempts at adding in spaces, I have had no luck. One way that I tried to do it was replacing the GridSpec line above with:

```
space = 0.01
grid = plt.GridSpec(2, 2, wspace = space, hspace = space*ratio, left = 0, right = 1, top = 1, bottom = 0, height_ratios=[dim1, xpix*(1-space)/2])
```

Sometimes depending on the space, image size, or number of pixels this seems to work, but a lot of the time it does not. I have tried several other things including using a 3*3 GridSpec with wspace = 0, hspace = 0 and using the middle row/column for spacing. I also tried using multiple GridSpec's and specifying the top, bottom, left, and right for each to get equal spacing and aligned edges. All of these attempts yielded similar results. One other important thing is that the I do need to have square pixels for each of the arrays (I noticed that a lot of the examples/other questions regarding GridSpec use subplots with nothing in them and it looks like the aspect ratio changes to get alignment?).

My ultimate goal is to be able to set an arbitrary space, size and input arrays and not have to worry about fiddling with things in order to get equal spacing with the edges aligned. Thank you in advance for any help!

Edit:

I am hoping that in the end the output will look like this: [Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwpfj.png) and that I will be able to choose the amount of space between the images.

Comment: Try to change your `GridSpec` like this : `grid = plt.GridSpec(2, 2,  height_ratios = [dim1, xpix/2])`, and add `plt.tight_layout()` at the end of your code .

Comment: @HMH1013 Thank you for the suggestion but it unfortunately did not work. The edges of the bottom plots are outside the top plot and the spacing is not equal when I tried it.

Comment: Because your figure is not square, change `fig = plt.figure(figsize = (size, size))` ?

Comment: @HMH1013 Unfortunately that is not the problem either. The whole figure should not be square (at least in the vast majority of cases).

Comment: Can you draw out what you think should happen here?  Note that `aspect='equal'` is a pretty strong constraint on what the final axes shape will be so setting spacing etc will only give you minimum spacing, but the spaces can and usually will be larger.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Sure, I have updated the post. Is that sufficient/what you were looking for? I am aware it is a strong constraint. If I am thinking about it correctly, there should only be one figure size that will work to get the correct spacing (for a given space)? I vaguely remember reading in some post about how it was only the minimum spacing, but thought if I got the figure size and height ratios correct that I would be able to get the correct spacing.